# Enables TLS 1.1 and 1.2 on Windows Server 2k8 (non R2)

Tags: windows-server-2008, tls1.2

Has anyone been able to get TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 working on Windows 2k8 SP2 (non R2).  The support just recently came out  [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019276/update-to-add-support-for-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-in-windows-server-2008-s).  I have gone through installed the updated and did the registry entries and it doesn't appear to be enabled.  Is there a way to check with out just looking at registry entries?

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest to test that your IIS configuration has been updated.

The Security tab under Chrome's developer tools will also indicate what protocol, key exchange, and cipher suite are used.