# TLS 1.2 on Windows Server 2008 NOT R2 Patch

Tags: windows-server-2008, tls1.2

From what I've read, Microsoft has removed all the hard-coded TLS 1.0 stuff from Windows Server 2008 Standard in a patch. Link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019276/update-to-add-support-for-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-in-windows-server-2008-s

A few weeks ago, one of my partners began demanding TLS 1.2, and I am trying to make it work on Windows Server 2008 utilizing this new patch. I am running a fairly simple .NET Framework 4.0 service that runs well on Windows Server 2008 R2, and previously ran just fine on this box before our partner's TLS 1.2 switchover. The error I began getting, and am still getting, is "The requested security protocol is not supported."

Following the instructions in Method 2 of that link, with SP2 already installed, I updated the registry as specified, ran the stand-alone update, and restarted the server. Nothing changed and I am still getting "The requested security protocol is not supported."

Has anyone else tried this update and succeeded? A similar question and I assume similar problem was asked on August 3rd, 2017: [Enables TLS 1.1 and 1.2 on Windows Server 2k8 (non R2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45473627/enables-tls-1-1-and-1-2-on-windows-server-2k8-non-r2), but I have reviewed the results from ssllabs and the server most certainly does not process TLS 1.2.

Comment: Did you figure this out? Im getting the same problem.

Comment: Negative. I have not taken this to Microsoft because we decided to just stand up a new server, but it may be worth asking them.